# PHP generate javascript objects with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, php

I did a function that generates from a php array a javascript object, for instance

```
$this->routes = array(
        'Module' => array(
            'Route1' => $renderer->url('route1', array('lang' => $lang_short)),
            'Route2' => $renderer->url('route1', array('lang' => $lang_short)),
        )
    );
```

My function will generate a javascript object like

```
{Static: {Module: {Route1: 'route1', Route2: 'route2'}}}
```

So I can access this in js like

```
Static.Module.Route1
```

The "problem" is the method I made handles arrays just with 2 nested arrays, not more.
What would be a nice and easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Change your method to handle `n` nested arrays? I really don't know what you want from us...

Answer (score 4):

Use the native [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, instead of your custom function.

Comment: you'r totally right, I guess I did not think about this as I wanted  to write my own. thanks